# Zoom In/out a textview while holding the textview

Tags: android, scale, pinchzoom

I am able to zoom in/out the text view when my fingers are around the textview (remember not placed on the textview) but the problem is that when I try to zoom in or out while keeping my both fingers on  the text view it doesn't work.

This is my activity where I am performing the zoom in/out and moving the textview on the screen at runtime

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView  tv;
    EditText et;
    Button ok;
    float dX, dY;


    ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtoshow);
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnok);



        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettext);
        String abc = et.getText().toString();

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

                String abc = et.getText().toString();
                et.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ok.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tv.setText(abc);

                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tv.setRotation(progress);
            }
        });
        tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if(motionEvent.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
//                    view.setX(motionEvent.getRawX() - view.getWidth());
//                    view.setY(motionEvent.getRawY() - view.getHeight());




                        view.animate()
                                .x(motionEvent.getRawX() + dX)
                                .y(motionEvent.getRawY() + dY)
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();






                }
                else if (motionEvent.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {



                    dX = view.getX() - motionEvent.getRawX();
                    dY = view.getY() - motionEvent.getRawY();


                }
                else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {


                    return true;
                }



                return true;
            }

        });

        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new simpleOnScaleGestureListener());




        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float size = tv.getTextSize();
            Log.d("TextSizeStart", String.valueOf(size));

            float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            Log.d("Factor", String.valueOf(factor));


            float product = size*factor;
            Log.d("TextSize", String.valueOf(product));
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);

            size = tv.getTextSize();
            Log.d("TextSizeEnd", String.valueOf(size));


            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of overriding activities on Touch 
you can do it like this

```
        tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            event.setLocation(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());
            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            return true;
        }
    });'
```

using above your zoom will start working when inside the text view .
For the touch outside of the text view setOnTouch Listener to the textView's parent and proceed as above